# Android Mediaplayer control on notification bar like Samsung Radio App

Tags: android, notifications, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications, multimedia

All
I'm a Android Developer from Argentina I'm developing an app to listening the Audio streaming for a local radio station. This app should work for Android OS for 2.3 and >4.0 I'm including a play/pause button into a custom notification, all works fine on Android >4.0 but with 2.3 I could see that is not possible to detect push on the button, my notification is like that (my goal is that the notification work same in all android version)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5qh7.jpg

I use this Samsung's radio App for Android 2.3 and this allow push buttons to control the Radio and change stations.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziiVw.png

This controls are above the notifications bar section, so I'm not sure if this an improving including by Samsung into this rom or is possible made something similar with android api.

If anybody has any idea about this issue I will appreciate any tip or suggestion.

Thanks in advance. Regards.

notifications android-mediaplayer and